# Django rest framework social oauth2

Tags: django, rest, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make an API for an iOS application using django(front end will be swift.) I do not ve much experience in this subject so when they wanted me to make a registration/login I immediately searched for documentations and found this.

https://github.com/PhilipGarnero/django-rest-framework-social-oauth2

In installation I did everything exactly same until

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ...
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        ...
        'oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication',
        'rest_framework_social_oauth2.authentication.SocialAuthentication',
    ),
}
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    ...
   'rest_framework_social_oauth2.backends.DjangoOAuth2',
   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

The reason I am struggling in here is that I do not ve any

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {  } and AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ( ) in my settings.py
```

Should I add them manually to settings.py?
And in the github code setings.py is the following.

```
from django.conf import settings

PROPRIETARY_BACKEND_NAME = getattr(settings, 'PROPRIETARY_BACKEND_NAME', "Django")
```

Should I do this or can I keep my settings.py with that long code?

Answer (score 0):

if your plan is to use only restframework do a normal registration, and provide token on login.

You can use  'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
in REST_FRAMEWORK, for AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS use 'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend' , this implies that you are using django authentication to authenticate and giving restframework token for further communication, from that moment when you communicate use that token along with the header.